# Where do Yordles come from?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm interested in learning more about where Tristana, Teemo, Rumble and the rest of the Yordles come from.

What is the name of their home city and where can I find out more about it?

Comment: Google is such a smartass.. http://www.google.com.br/search?q=Yordles

Comment: They seem to be an exclusive race from LoL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yordles come from Bandle City in the southeastern part of Valoran.

Bandle City is home to Teemo, Tristana, Rumble, Hiemerdinger, Corki, Poppy, Veiger, Kennen, and is also Amumu's birthplace.

For more information on this city,refer to this [League of Legends wiki article.](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Bandle_City)